# How to set up Mockito mock to use same answer for multiple different method calls

Tags: java, mockito

I want to test the http layer for an spring boot rest application. For this mocked the service to answer the calls of the controller.

Since i have many methods (e.g. findBy...) that expect a list to be returned by the service i want to stub all calls at once and all should be answered by the same answer.

For one it is:

```
when(someService.getAll()).thenReturn(listOfSomeElements);
```

Is there a way in Mockito to setup same answer for multiple calls that all accept the same answer? Something like

```
when(someService.getAll(), someService.getSome(), someService.getFew()).thenReturn(listOfSomeElements);
```

or

```
doReturn(listOfSomeElements).when(someService.getAll()).when( someService.getSome()).when(someService.getFew())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store method references and then iterate over them

```
interface Foo {
    String foo();
}

interface Bar {
    String bar();
}

@Mock
Foo mockFoo;
@Mock
Bar mockBar;

@Test
public void someTest()
{
    List<Supplier<String>> suppliers = Arrays.asList(mockFoo::foo, mockBar::bar);
    for (Supplier<String> supplier : suppliers)
    {
        when(supplier.get()).thenReturn("Blah");
    }

    assertEquals("Blah", mockFoo.foo());
    assertEquals("Blah", mockBar.bar());
}
```

This test is runnable and passes.

Comment: pretty fency :-). Probably i'll try to modify by using also stream api (for isn't needed any more nowadays :-D)

Comment: You can, but it isn't any better than what I've already given you `Stream.<Supplier<String>>of(mockFoo::foo, mockBar::bar).forEach(supplier -> when(supplier.get()).thenReturn("Blah"));`

Comment: you are absolutely right it is only to maximize fanciness :-D (not readability )